# ng-class : Assign a single class to multiple expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can we have one class being assigned to multiple expressions (basically boolean values) ?

Like for example I have class '**wrong-date-entered**' and multiple expression that can be assigned to it such as `$scope.futureDateEntered` , `$scope.pastDateEntered` and `$scope.invalidDateEntered`.

I know one way to do it as

```
    <div ng-class="{class1: expressionData1, class1: expressionData2}">
    </div>
```

But, I would be using this way too frequently and would want a shorter way out, maybe something like this:-

```
    <div ng-class="{class1: expressionData1, expressionData2}"></div>
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `||` operator

```
 <div ng-class="{class1: expressionData1 || expressionData2}"></div>
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Combine both conditions in one like `(expressionData1) || (expressionData2)`

```
<div ng-class="{
      class1: expressionData1 || expressionData2
}"></div>
```

You can use any number of conditions combined properly if you have to use one class for them, no need to write separatly.